# Evaluate string command in Scala from REPL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a way to evaluate a arbitrary string from Scala as if the same text was entered into the Scala REPL directly?  I mean, I would like to do something like this:

```
scala> eval("val x = 42")

scala> x
res2: Int = 42
```

Since the Scala REPL is accepting commands in an eval loop using jline (I believe) and then compiling/interpreting it, there has to be a way to submit an arbitrary line of text. I am willing to hack the Scala REPL if necessary.

Comment: There might be a simpler way, but worst case you can always write it to a file and use load()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No REPL hacking necessary—just switch to power user mode, which gives you access to the current [`scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain) as `intp`:

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP SPIZ **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._ and definitions._ also imported **
** Try  :help,  vals.<tab>,  power.<tab>    **

scala> intp.interpret("val x = 42")
x: Int = 42
res0: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.package.IR.Result = Success

scala> x
res1: Int = 42
```

This works since at least 2.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

Another opportunity is to use [Eval](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala) from Twitter Utility:

```
val x: Int = new Eval()("1 + 1")
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to use Eval to do what the question asks—to evaluate a string defining a `val` and have that variable be visible to the REPL (if I'm wrong please correct me).

Comment: @TravisBrown you're right: the same level of comfort is not possible.