# How to transform a decimal-point-separated string into a multi-dimensional hash?

Tags: json, scala, dictionary

Morning StackOverflow,

I have a bit of a interesting question today, I was intrigued to know what would be the best way going about converting a decimal separated string into a multi-dimension hash.

For example:

Let say I have the string `some.settings.woo = bla`

I am looking to get a outcome something like this

```
{
  "some": {
    "settings": {
      "woo": "bla"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not quite to sure how to go about it effectively

Thanks, Liam

Comment: Your format looks a lot like HOCON.  If so, you could use Typesafe's Config library to transform it into JSON: https://github.com/typesafehub/config

Comment: I would also look at typesafe config and see if it works for you before you go for something more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ryan and his comment I was reminded of typesafe's config library which made this a really easy walk in the park. It is pretty much a simple two-liner, e.g.

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseString("apache.port=80\nnginx.bind.port=443")
println(conf.root().render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise()))
```

Returns the following JSON

```
{
  "apache": { 
    "port":80
  },
  "nginx": {
    "bind": {
      "port": 443
     }
   }
}
```

This made file stupidly simple, Thanks Ryan!

Library link: https://github.com/typesafehub/config

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Rapture's](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-json) `JsonBuffer`. Please mind that there's probably a bajillion ways to do this in Scala as [JSON libraries are plentiful in the language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442630/1407656). This is just a way I happen to know, feel free to explore other libraries.

To quote the docs from the github page I linked to:

> An empty `JsonBuffer` may be created with
>
> ```
> val jb = JsonBuffer.empty
> ```
>
> and can be mutated with instructions such as
>
> ```
> jb.fruit.name = "apple"
> jb.fruit.color = "green"
> jb.fruit.varieties = List("cox")
> ```
>
> resulting in
>
> ```
> {
>   "fruit": {
>     "name": "apple",
>     "color": "green",
>     "varieties": ["cox"]
>   }
> }
> ```

For more information, refer to the [docs concerning mutable JSON representations](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-json#user-content-mutable-json).

If the input you have is in a string format, you'll have to evaluate it somehow. Here's [a Stackoverflow question on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11923378/1407656). Be careful though and make sure the input comes from a trusted source.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use well tested library, but you can also consider this:

```
  val parts = "some.settings.woo = bla".split('.')   
  val json = parts.init
    .foldRight("{" + parts.last.replace("=", ":") + "}")("{" + _ + ":" + _ + "}")

  // {some:{settings:{woo : bla}}}
```