# Addition of numbers recursively in Scala

Tags: scala

In this Scala code I'm trying to analyze a string that contains a sum (such as `12+3+5`) and return the result (`20`). I'm using regex to extract the first digit and parse the trail to be added recursively. My issue is that since the regex returns a String, I cannot add up the numbers. Any ideas?

```
object TestRecursive extends App {

  val plus = """(\w*)\+(\w*)""".r

  println(parse("12+3+5"))

  def parse(str: String) : String = str match {

    // sum   
    case plus(head, trail) => parse(head) + parse(trail)

    case _ => str
  }


}
```

Comment: Why not simply `println(12 + 3 + 5)`? ;)

Comment: I'm trying to build a calculator for the user enters a string and the program calculates the result

Comment: @csharpfolk that doesn't work as the parse function returns String

Comment: @ps0604 that was just the *idea*, you need to change `parse` signature to return Int of course

Comment: @csharpfolk that's the point of the question, how to make the function return String and Int, depending on what is returned

Comment: whats the purpose of `parse` - to evaluate the expression, what will be value of the expression - a number. so let `parse` always return number like here `parse(s: String): Int` - everything should compile after that change - thats magic of recursion

Comment: Try look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923378/evaluate-string-command-in-scala-from-repl), might save you the hard work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the `parser combinators` for an application like this.

`"""(\w*)\+(\w*)""".r` also matches `"+"` or `"23+"` or `"4 +5" // but captures it only in the first group`.

what you could do might be

```
scala> val numbers = "[+-]?\\d+"
numbers: String = [+-]?\d+
                                   ^

scala> numbers.r.findAllIn("1+2-3+42").map(_.toInt).reduce(_ + _)
res4: Int = 42

scala> numbers.r.findAllIn("12+3+5").map(_.toInt).reduce(_ + _)
res5: Int = 20
```

Comment: what if I need to add division and multiplication?

Comment: then you have to use a real parser.